# How to add images from mysql database to Tkinter Treeview

Tags: python, image, tkinter, treeview

I'm Trying to figure out how to display image from Mysql Database to Tkinter Treeview. I was able to get and insert the product id but the image is not showing. Any help is so much appreciated.

```py
try:
    global img, record
    select_query = "select * from tblproduct"
    c.execute(select_query)
    record = c.fetchone()
    count = 0
    for record in c:
        prod_img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(record[11]))
        prod_img.thumbnail((50, 50))
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(prod_img)
        product_view.insert(parent="", index="end", image=img, values=(record[0]))
        count += 1
except mysql.connector.Error as error:
    messagebox.showerror(title='Error', message=str(error))
```

[image]

The img is supposedly after the product ID. Disregard the column head title. I changed it to Product Name and will change it to Product Image if I will get a solution for this problem.

[image]

I tried checking similar post and applied some modification but I was not able to fix it.

Comment: Did you set `show="headings"` when creating the treeview `product_view`? If yes, then no image will be shown because image will be shown in the *tree column* which is hidden.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you for your response. To simplify, I just need to show image from mysql database to tkinter treeview .